# Is this issue Margin collapse and how do other handle this optimally

Tags: html, css

I am learning HTML and CSS and have come across an issue where I am getting a big gap between sibling elements.

I have done some searching on stack overflow and the web and believe this is caused by margin collapse.

I have added three commented-out lines in the CSS (*two in **.home-section** selector and one in the **.products-section** selector*)and each of these separately seems to fix the issue BUT I don't know if any these are the optimal solution or have I not structured my code properly elsewhere.  I don't want to develop any bad habits.

Any help greatly appreciated and if you are able to point me to any beginner oriented reading on the subject that would be excellent as well.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/pjsmyth/pen/ZZoyVG)

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Archivo+Black|Montserrat:400,800|Sacramento" rel="stylesheet">

    <title>Test banner</title>

  </head>

  <body>

    <header class="banner">

      <div class="logo">
        <img src="../images/iconfinder_umbrella-rain-summer-sun-protection_2189569.svg" alt="Umbrella logo">
      </div>

      <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#products">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li class="collapsed-menu"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-bars fa-lg"></i></a></li>
      </ul>

    </header>

    <section id="home" class="home-section">

      <div class="text-block">
        <h6>What we do</h6>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

      </div>

    </section>

    <section id="products" class="products-section">
      <div class="product1">
        <h6>Product 1</h6>
      </div>
    </section>

  </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.banner {
  height: 7vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: #096386;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
}

.logo {
  margin-left: 3vw;
  height: 7vh;
  line-height: 7vh;
  display: inline-block;
}
.logo img {
  height: 6vh;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.nav {
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
  margin-right: 3vw;
  line-height: 7vh;
}
.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: auto;
}
.nav li a {
  margin: 1vh;
  color: #f0eec8;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0.5vh 1vh;
}
.nav li a:hover {
  background-color: #f0eec8;
  padding: 0.5vh 1vh;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #096386;
}
.nav li a i {
  color: #f0eec8;
}
.nav .collapsed-menu {
  display: none;
}

.home-section {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  //border: 1px red solid;
  //margin-bottom: -15vh;
}
.home-section::after {
  content: "";
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: lightblue;
  opacity: 0.6;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
.home-section .text-block {
  width: 40vw;
  margin-top: 15vh;
  margin-left: 10vh;
  padding: 2vh;
  position: relative;
  max-height: 70vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.home-section .text-block::after {
  content: "";
  background-color: #b3b3b3;
  border-radius: 3vh;
  opacity: 0.8;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
.home-section .text-block h6 {
  font-family: "Archivo Black", sans-serif;
  font-size: 3em;
  padding-bottom: 1vh;
}
.home-section .text-block p {
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  text-align: justify;
}

.products-section {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: #f0eec8;
  z-index: 20;
  //margin-top: -15vh;
}

/*# sourceMappingURL=main.css.map */
```

Comment: Hi man
Things that you are doing is good as beginner, Here is pure css based tab layout i found on codepen
https://codepen.io/renatorib/pen/rlpfj

You can take it as reference

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **:before or :after pseudo element** by `position:absolute;` so you need to make parent as `position:relative;` , change `margin-top:7vh;` as per header height and other padding changes

You can reference from [cssnewbie](https://cssnewbie.com/using-after-before-with-position-absolute/#.XLmsh5gzaUk) and `margin-padding` from [here](https://medium.com/frontendshortcut/margin-vs-padding-c1fc8ea8bfaf)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.banner {
  height: 7vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: #096386;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
}

.logo {
  margin-left: 3vw;
  height: 7vh;
  line-height: 7vh;
  display: inline-block;
}
.logo img {
  height: 6vh;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.nav {
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
  margin-right: 3vw;
  line-height: 7vh;
}
.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: auto;
}
.nav li a {
  margin: 1vh;
  color: #f0eec8;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0.5vh 1vh;
}
.nav li a:hover {
  background-color: #f0eec8;
  padding: 0.5vh 1vh;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #096386;
}
.nav li a i {
  color: #f0eec8;
}
.nav .collapsed-menu {
  display: none;
}

.home-section {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position:relative;
  padding: 2vh 0vh;
}
.home-section::after {
  content: "";
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: lightblue;
  opacity: 0.6;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
.home-section .text-block {
  width: 40vw;
  margin-top: 7vh;
  padding-top:7vh;
  margin-left: 10vh;
  padding: 2vh;
  position: relative;
  max-height: 70vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.home-section .text-block::after {
  content: "";
  background-color: #b3b3b3;
  border-radius: 3vh;
  opacity: 0.8;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
.home-section .text-block h6 {
  font-family: "Archivo Black", sans-serif;
  font-size: 3em;
  padding-bottom: 1vh;
}
.home-section .text-block p {
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  text-align: justify;
}

.products-section {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: #f0eec8;
  z-index: 20;
  //margin-top: -15vh;
}

/*# sourceMappingURL=main.css.map */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Archivo+Black|Montserrat:400,800|Sacramento" rel="stylesheet">

    <title>Test banner</title>

  </head>

  <body>

    <header class="banner">

      <div class="logo">
        <img src="../images/iconfinder_umbrella-rain-summer-sun-protection_2189569.svg" alt="Umbrella logo">
      </div>

      <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#products">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li class="collapsed-menu"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-bars fa-lg"></i></a></li>
      </ul>

    </header>

    <section id="home" class="home-section">

      <div class="text-block">
        <h6>What we do</h6>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        
      </div>

    </section>

    <section id="products" class="products-section">
      <div class="product1">
        <h6>Product 1</h6>
      </div>
    </section>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it's a margin issue. Also, most of your stuff are too close to each other. Elements need space to "breathe". I really liked that your sections took up a whole screen, as an example.

Here are some guidelines:

• Use the font size as distances. Set the font for body text to, lets say 16px, and then use "1rem" for any kind distance. From text to border, from element to element, from parent to child element, etc.
• Use *padding* instead of *margin*. If you need to place something, like your `.text-block` in `.home-section`, use *padding* for `.home-section` instead of *margins* in its child elements.
• Use *min-width* and *min-height* instead *width* and *height*, unless the layout breaks if an element overflows.

Here is something I wrote as guidelines for doing layouts for books, but most are applicable on web pages as well:

http://www.erebaltor.se/rickard/typography/

Note, all these are **guidelines**. Sometimes you need to break them.